# Is there a word for people who love everything?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

The closest I could get was *xenophile*. Also, *optimistic* would be a close second and I say that because I don't think that *optimistic* is a better description than *xenophile* because *xenophile* actually includes love.

Comment: Do you have a context?

Comment: @simchona: Context is unnecessary, I think. It won't change the answer.

Comment: How about "tasteless"? :)

Comment: @terdon: undiscriminating, imperceptive, insensitive, obtuse, & abnormal as well. :-)

Comment: Would you define Buddha like that ? Insensitive ? Imperceptive ? Obtuse ?

Comment: What do you mean by _everything_? People, chocolate, roses and kangaroos? Laziness, lying, infanticide, genocide?

Comment: Facebook user, perhaps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Omniphile: *omni* = every; *-phile* = love. *Xeno-* = foreign things, so *[xenophile](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/xenophile)* means lover of foreign things, not lover of everything.

Comment: "omnilove", could it be?

Comment: @xjaphx: _Omniphilia_ is the proper Latinate term, but that's a description of the type of indiscriminate love this type of person has, not of the person, which requires the suffix /-phile/.

Comment: You might want to note that _omniphile_ is a neologism.

Comment: @coleopterist: Yes, it is, but it works according to the principles of English & Latin word-building. Anyone who understands Latin roots will understand _omniphile_. Fortunately, one doesn't have to be a Pollyanna to be an omniphile. I knew one of the latter when I was an undergraduate. Every morning she put on this happy face & wailed "Good morning, everyone!" Everyone hated her. Everybody else did too. Never a discouraging word & never a cloudy sky in her little world. Truly a cow in a manger.

Comment: "cow in a manger" - excellent phrase, and one I have never heard before. Thanks!

Comment: @user21497 I was confused there for a second - thought you were saying 'dog in the manger'!

Comment: I like it, but one slight problem here is that the omni- part is Latin, while the -phile part is Greek.  This kind of mixing is generally frowned upon. As an alternative, consider _pantophile_, which is defined at https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pantophile as "a person who loves everyone and everything".

Answer (score 5):

Besides the already-offered neologism *omniphile*, consider *[Pollyanna](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Pollyanna)*:

> One who is persistently cheerful and optimistic, even when given cause not to be so.
>   [*eg*]    You call her an optimist, but I call her an obnoxious Pollyanna.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be philomania (phile means 'love', for example, my middle name is Philip, which means lover of horses). Omniphile is someone who wants to have intercourse with everyone/thing.

Comment: Can you back up your guess with references?

Comment: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/philo-, https://www.behindthename.com/name/philip; additionally, 'misomania' is a term for someone who hates everything, in psychologically, has an abnormal feel of being persecuted and being hated by everyone. That is all the references I have, but I think I am right, not to brag or anything.